# Printing strings with conditions in python

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

I am trying to complete a short python code to output names of ducks. For those ducks whose first letters are 'O' and 'Q', they must be printed with a 'u' after the first letter. I have tried out my code but for some reason it prints the u with every single letter whether it is a 'Q' or any other letter.

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"

for p in prefixes:
    print(p + suffix)
    if(p == 'O' or 'Q'):
        print(p + 'u' + suffix)
```

Comment: p == 'O' or p == 'Q'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

if p == 'O' or p == 'Q':

Comment: Thanks lol such a simple solution I'm an idiot

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this expression:

```
p == 'O' or 'Q'
```

This evaluates to `(p == 'O') or 'Q'` and since the boolean value of a non-empty string is always `True`, the expression is always `True`.

You want:

```
p in ['O', 'Q']
```

You could also do `p == 'O' or p == 'Q' or p == etc.`, but that gets very repetitive.

So, you get:

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"

for p in prefixes:
    if p in ['O', 'Q']:
        print(p + 'u' + suffix)
    else:
        print(p + suffix)
```

Comment: umm I dont get how that would help, there is no way to check for the condition if I used that.

Comment: I added the answer in context of your code, does that help?